# Django GROUP BY without aggregate

Tags: django, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to write the following query in Postgresql using Django ORM:

```
SELECT t.id, t.field1 FROM mytable t JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE .... GROUP BY id
```

Note that there is NO aggregate function (like SUM, COUNT etc.) in the SELECT part.
By the way, it's a perfectly legal SQL to GROUP BY primary key only in Postgresql.

How do I write it in Django ORM?

I saw workarounds like adding `.annotate(dummy=Count('*'))` to the queryset (but it slows down the execution) or introducing a dummy custom aggregate function (but it's a dirty hack). How to do it in a clean way?

Comment: That is basically: `SELECT DISTINCT ON(t.id) t.id, t.field1 ... WHERE ....`(with no `GROUP BY`) and that is available here [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/) as *distinct() ... On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query.*.